# Is there a standard procedure for turning a singly linked list into a std::vector?

Tags: c++11, struct, stdvector, singly-linked-list

Having

```cpp
struct addrinfo {
           int              ai_flags;
           int              ai_family;
           int              ai_socktype;
           int              ai_protocol;
           socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
           struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
           char            *ai_canonname;
           struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
typedef struct addrinfo* PADDRINFOA;
```

the only way I've found to represent it (thanks to Jefffrey) as std::vector is to declare

```cpp
typedef struct sAddrInfo{
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    //no next pointer
}NoListAddrInfo;
```

and then

```cpp
PADDRINFOA next = myAddrInfo;
ret->addr_vect.clear();
for(size_t i = 0;next != NULL;i++)
{
    ret->addr_vect.push_back(sAddrInfo());
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_flags = next->ai_flags;
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_family = next->ai_family;
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_socktype = next->ai_socktype;
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_protocol = next->ai_protocol;
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_addrlen = next->ai_addrlen;
    ret->addr_vect[i].ai_addr = next->ai_addr;
    next = next->ai_next;
}
```

Is there any way to do this using less instructions?

Comment: If you want to use brackets you'd better stick to `vector`

Comment: @bobah I need to wrap the structure into a list or a vector

Comment: @Strelok: That's not a question. A question typically ends in a question mark.

Comment: Is there a clean way to wrap the structure in a c++ data type?

Comment: It's clear that you didn't try it. You seem to think there is something magical about `struct`s that make them unpalatable to C++ standard containers, but this is not the case. You are expected to try things out, instead of simply coming here asking for code to be created for you.

Comment: @Lightness Ironically I've been coding since 4PM and I didn't want spend time for something I can't easily figure out on my own after 3 hours of coding. I bow before your wisdom my majesty, your constructive comment shall be treated as rule amongst the lesser coders.

Comment: Three hours is *nowhere near* enough of your own time and effort. Come back after three *days*!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think a human can code for 72 hours in a row, can you?

Comment: Yes. It's quite common, in fact, when you're up against internal deadlines and strong commercial pressures. But, besides all that, you know full well what I meant.

Comment: I guess I've underestimed drugs usage. I'm going to remove this question as all answer are nearly useless or OffTopic

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've completely reworked the question. Does this make any sense yo you now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case your structure should look like this:

```
struct addrinfo {
   int              ai_flags;
   int              ai_family;
   int              ai_socktype;
   int              ai_protocol;
   socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
   struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
   char            *ai_canonname;
   // notice the lack of `ai_next`
};
```

Then if you really want to keep the linked list you should either use [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) or [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=list) (doubly linked list):

```
std::forward_list<addrinfo> list;
```

otherwise if you want to use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which from your example usage would fit nicely) you would just need to change it to:

```
std::vector<addrinfo> vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to put one of those structs in a vector...

```
typedef struct addrinfo ADDRINFO;

std::vector<ADDRINFO> myvec;

myvec.push_back(ADDRINFO());

myvec[0].ai_flags= 42;
```

Comment: Should be `.` instead of `->`.

Comment: And the `typedef` should be removed. Even if you keep it, don't call it `PADDRINFO`, because that conventionally signifies a pointer type (`P`).

Comment: Thanks - sample above edited as per Nabla/Lightness' comments

Answer (score 0):

Structs are just classes.

```
std::vector<addrinfo> myvec;
myvec.push_back(addrinfo());
myvec[0].ai_flags = 42;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a pointer to addrinfo with no values beside ai_flags?

Comment: I see no pointers in the example given.  What you *do* have is a vector that has 1 element in it, namely an addrinfo.  You access it exactly as you see written.

Comment: @paul the problem is I need to put a already filled linked list of addrinfos(addrinfo**) aka the result of getaddrinfo in a std::list<addrinfo>

Comment: You should really read your C++ book and get a grasp of the basics. You shouldn't attempt to rush programming, or to cheat by learning from the internet, one malformed question at a time :p